# Angular 2 shows blank page when re compile

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one issue working with Angular2, I'm launching my application using the `ng serve` command, in my console I see this:

[Angular re compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ZP2.png)

The previous image shows the Log when the application is recompiled, after that the application is reloaded and I see the next:[blank page angular 2 on recompilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztFv3.png)

Only a blank page, also I notice this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="./">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Icons -->
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/daterangepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/loaders.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ladda/dist/ladda.min.css">
<link rel="manifest" href="assets/manifest.json">

<script src="node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="app header-fixed  aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
<script>window.__theme = 'bs4';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is not included any of the code for Angular 2, If I kill the process and relaunch the application using again `ng serve` i got this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="./">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Icons -->
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/daterangepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/loaders.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ladda/dist/ladda.min.css">
<link rel="manifest" href="assets/manifest.json">

<script src="node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="app header-fixed  aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
<script>window.__theme = 'bs4';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Bottom of this line of code `<script>window.__theme = 'bs4';</script>` is the Angular compiled scripts.

What is bad in my configuration?

This is my package.json content:

`{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "ag-grid": "^9.0.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.2.1",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "handsontable": "^0.31.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-handsontable": "^0.48.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}`

Comment: Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Any error, all looks good.